# How to plot the computational graph and derive the update procedure of parameters using the backpropagation algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, loss-function, algorithms, backpropagation

*Please help me to solve this problem without a code (ps: this is a written problem):*

Given the following loss function, please **plot the computational graph**, and **derive the update procedure** of parameters using the backpropagation algorithm,
[image]

where $W$ = {$W_1, W_2, W_3, W_4$}, $b$ = {$b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4$} denote the parameters; $x ∈ R^d$ indicates the input features; $y ∈ R$ is the ground-truth label.